Why does allylic bromination occur with N-bromosuccinimide?
For the purpose of allylic bromination on an alkene, say propan-1-ene, N-bromosuccinimide (NBS) is added to HBr in carbon tetrachloride which leads to the formation of bromine. The bromine, in the presence of light, gives bromine radical which replaces a hydrogen atom by a bromine atom on the allylic site.
My question is that why does a radical process happen. When bromine is added to propene in carbon tetrachloride it leads to formation of cyclobromonium. Thus, the expected product must be 1,2-dibromopropane. Why then, in the presence of NBS does a radical substitution take place?

NBS generates $\ce{Br2}$ in low concentration and, in the presence of light, forms Br radicals in a chain reaction. IIRC the rate is first order in bromine. The addition of $\ce{Br2}$ to a double bond is done at higher concentrations with no intense light source. The rate is second order in $\ce{Br2}$. BTW: I've done the NBS reaction without adding HBr, which may be formed surreptitiously.
